# Error in sharing on Twitter from my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

We are using UIActivityViewController in our app for sharing info but when we try to share some information on Twitter, we get an error “Twitter failed to send”.

[image]

Comment: @halfer Sorry for that and Thanks for your guidance. I will remember it in Future. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Twitter iteself. as of V7.54 on iOS the issue is resolved.